# Is it legal for a stock broker to restrict trading on a specific stock?

Tags: united-states, sec

Brokers like Robinhood are restricting purchases of GameStop stock driving the price down. Is this market manipulation and against the law? Or does the SEC permit this? You can find an article talking about this here,

- [Robinhood blocks new purchases of GameStop stock](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/robinhood-blocks-new-purchases-of-gamestop-stock-11611846335)
- [Robinhood, TD Ameritrade restrict trading of GameStop, AMC stock](https://www.cnet.com/personal-finance/robinhood-app-td-ameritrade-restrict-trading-of-gamestop-amc-stock/)

Comment: I guess a separate question would be whether it breaches their service contract with those customers.  Probably not, since Robinhood wrote that contract and it's likely to be favorable to them.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Good question. I was going to ask that. Would you want to ask a separate question on this topic? If you do, please let me know. I would like to see the answer.

Comment: @Hans: I probably won't, so feel free to go ahead if you want.

Answer (score 8):

Brokers are not required by law to trade every available stock. They are ultimately private business people, not public services.

Also, when there is circumstantial evidence that illegal securities fraud and market manipulation is underway in the shares of a particular security, as in the case of GameStop, there may be more liability exposure from allowing the broker's customers to trade in the stock, potentially exposing them to securities fraud, than there is to barring trading in the stock.

Also relevant: "[Nasdaq CEO Friedman says the exchange will halt trading in a stock if they link unusual activity to social media chatter](https://markets.businessinsider.com/news/stocks/nasdaq-monitors-social-media-halts-unusual-trading-friedman-market-manipulation-2021-1-1030011156).":

> Friedman said the Nasdaq's role as a "self-regulatory organization" is
> to make sure activity in the market is "legitimate" and to root out
> manipulation in the market. She did not detail what kind of technology
> the Nasdaq uses to "evaluate social media chatter," but she said if
> the Nasdaq can match unusual trading with social media activity, the
> exchange will halt the stock and potentially engage with the SEC to
> evaluate and investigate.
>
> One illegal market manipulation activity that the SEC goes after is a
> "pump-and-dump" scheme.  An investor buys a stock, and then publicly
> "pumps" it, by spreading a rumor or another catalyst for the stock go
> up. Other people see the rumors and buy the stock, causing the price
> to rise. The person who originated the rumor sells the stock to them
> at a higher price in a "dump," and takes the profits.  Friedman said
> the Nasdaq collaborates with the FINRA and SEC to identify and
> investigate pump and dump schemes, but she said it's unclear whether
> the current Reddit activity qualifies as a pump and dump scheme.
>
> "Regulators kind of have to catch up with the technology that's now
> available," Friedman said.

Background on the economic and regulatory motivators for the action taken can be found [here](https://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2021/01/why-was-share-trading-restricted.html):

> [T]here is a two-day settlement between if you buy the stock today,
> those brokerage firms that you bought that stock on have to fund that
> trade with the clearing central house called DTC for two whole days.
> And because of the volatility of stocks, DTC has made the cost of the
> collateral of the two-day holding period extremely expensive.

Comment: It may be relevant that they are not choosing to not trade the stock at all, they still allow sell orders. Only buying the stock is (temporarily) blocked while selling is possible, which is much more dubious than not trading the stock at all.

Comment: @blues The policy is that "“We continuously monitor the markets and make changes where necessary,” the statement reads. “In light of recent volatility, we are restricting transactions for certain securities to position closing only.”" This is a bit different from allowing sell and not buy. Sells of only an entire position of the stock are permitted to divest oneself of involvement in it. It is very unlikely that this would be illegal.

Comment: Does a stock broker that is managing my stocks have an agency relationship with me? Is there not a fiduciary obligation to allow me to liquidate stocks that I have in my portfolio with him? Your answer talks about the brokers legal obligations to the state? Do they not have legal obligations to me established by the state?

Comment: @EvanCarroll My answer doesn't talk about legal liability to the state, The liability exposure I am talking about is liability to customers who are defrauded by trading in a stock in which there is circumstantial evidence of active securities fraud in progress, if the customer suffers losses as a result. Brokers are sometimes fiduciaries and sometimes not. https://www.forbes.com/sites/davidmarotta/2018/05/28/new-sec-advice-rule-abandons-fiduciary-standard-for-brokers/?sh=7a36dc432600 The obligation to liquidate might be contractual but probably isn't fiduciary.

Comment: @owhilleke at least on the surface of it, it appears that the active securities fraud was happening on both sides though.  You claim that allowing to liquidate does not amount to only allowing sales, but that's an extremely tenuous argument.  Without some other supporting evidence, it strains credulity and can only serve to undermine confidence in capital markets.  Further, if they did not fulfill exercise orders on calls, then that would be a direct violation of call contracts and potentially fraudulent.

Comment: Does it breach the broker's service contract with its customers by refusing to execute their orders?

Comment: @Hans It depends upon what the contract says. Since they are drafted by lawyers for the broker, they typically contain lots of exculpatory provisions. Also, typically any dispute must be resolved in an arbitration forum that bars class action suits, does not create precedents and has been shown empirically to be biased towards brokers.